# Creating Dynamic Slides with Swiper.js in Ionic + Angular Not Appending New Slides

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

My swiper works statically, but when I attempt to add on new slides it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
        <swiper #slider (reachEnd)="end()" (swiper)="setSwiperInstance($event)" (slideChange)="loadNext()" [config]="config">
            <ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let emojiBlock of initalEmojiMessages">
  
              <ion-card class="emoji-card">
                <ion-card-content class="internal-card">
    
                      <div class="emoji-carrier">
                        <span class="emojis">{{emojiBlock.emojis}}</span>
                        <span class="emojis-words">{{emojiBlock.words}}</span>
                      </div>
                </ion-card-content>
              </ion-card>
              
            </ng-template>
          
        </swiper>
```

Once I reach the last slide, `end()` is called:

```
end() {
    let index = this.swiper.swiperRef.activeIndex++;
    let newEmojis = this.getEmojiSet();
    this.initalEmojiMessages.push(newEmojis);
    this.swiper.swiperRef.appendSlide(`
    <ng-template swiperSlide>
      
      <ion-card class="emoji-card">
        <ion-card-content class="internal-card">
        <p>hello world ${index}</p>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    
    </ng-template>
    `)
  }
```

This function both adds another emoji to the array `initalEmojiMessages` and adds a new slide through `this.swiper.swiperRef.appendSlide`. However neither method of adding more slides works.

This is what it looks like in action:

On last slide:
[image: last slide]

Attempting to go to next slide:
[image: attempt to next slide]

As you can see, the new slide does not lock into place, and the `appendSlide()` method worked while adding on the `ngFor` didn't work.

Anyone experienced this problem/knows how to make adding slides with swiper.js in ionic work?

Comment: Also want to note it is interesting that the `${index}` is 1, not 4 as there are already 3 slides from the 3 elements in the array.

Comment: you should update your Array and it will be appended to your slides.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but i came across a similar problem in next.js.
I found that a piece of CSS was causing this anomaly in conjunction with the number of slides in view.
I ended up commenting all the CSS out and slowly introducing it back in to find the offending styling.
Then it worked like a dream.
Not sure if this will help you with your problem but if you haven't tried this then it might be a place to start.